# Android: detect restarted service with START_REDELIVER_INTENT flag

Tags: android

My widget has a service attached to it to process various click "commands" which are passed through its intent.  I've also set `return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;` for the case of when the service is restarted to not give a nullPointerException when calling intent.getAction(); and the like.  The problem is, when the last intent was sent by one of the setOnClickPendingIntent calls I have, then when the service is restarted, it acts as if the user had clicked one of the viewId's.  e.g.

```
String command = intent.getAction();
int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID);
if(command.equals("some command")){
    //do something
}

...

remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.viewId,MyClass.makeControlPendingIntent(getApplicationContext(),"some command",appWidgetId));
```

Where makeControlPendingIntent is:

```
public static PendingIntent makeControlPendingIntent(Context context, String command, int appWidgetId) {
        Intent active = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
        active.setAction(command);
        active.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("myclass://widget/id/#"+command+appWidgetId), String.valueOf(appWidgetId));
        active.setData(data);
        return(PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, active, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    }
```

Is there something I can do to check if the service is being restarted so as to not run any of those commands in the case where Android restarts my service?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there something I can do to check if the service is being restarted so as to not run any of those commands in the case where Android restarts my service?

The flags parameter to `onStartCommand()` will contain `START_FLAG_REDELIVERY` if the `Intent` is being re-delivered. So, you can do something like this:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if ((flags & START_FLAG_REDELIVERY)!=0) { // if crash restart...
        // do something here
    }

    // rest of logic here
}
```

Comment: In this case, it may make more sense to return START_STICKY and check for a NULL Intent.